# How can I record all URL and IP outgoing traffic on my computer so I can see what people are up too

Tags: networking, email

I'm trying to get a list of all outgoing URL traffic that my computer makes.  This way I can know what my computer is making a request for.  Like for email or web browsing or the unity searching the web.  Then I want to mail the log hourly to an email address.  I already have EXIM4 as a mail server configured as an internet site.

My Netgear router on my other network already does this including email.
Netgear does it like this.

> [Site allowed: nlmobile.cdnak.neulion.com] from source 192.168.1.2, Monday, Oct 20,2014 08:00:53
>   [Site allowed: nfl.demdex.net] from source 192.168.1.2, Monday, Oct 20,2014 08:00:53
>   [Site allowed: d2b67tzkr07lta.cloudfront.net] from source 192.168.1.2, Monday, Oct 20,2014 08:00:44
>   [Site allowed: www.cerberusapp.com] from source 192.168.1.2, Monday, Oct 20,2014 08:00:41
>   [email sent to: fakeemail@localhosts] Monday, Oct 20,2014 07:01:01

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to take a loot at tcpspy (just type "sudo apt-cache search tcpspy" and install it if you like "sudo apt-get install tcpspy"...
ftp://ftp.tu-clausthal.de/pub/mirror/gnu/www/directory/tcpspy.html

This logs your tcp traffic... maybe you need something for udp, too!

Comment: This solves my problem.  I don't see anywhere to click to mark your solution as best.  You have my thanks.